# Metro UI/Store App, ARM and error C3861: 'Sleep': identifier not found

Tags: windows, visual-studio, arm

I'm having trouble detecting Metro UI/Store Apps, ARM apps and the headers that should be included.

I have a source file that needs `<windows.h>` for `VOID`, `LPVOID`, `HANDLE`, `LPHANDE` and some base services declarations like `WaitForMultipleObjects` and `Sleep`. The following works for a regular desktop program:

```c
#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(WIN64) || defined(_WIN64)
# define MYLIB_WIN32_AVAILABLE
#endif

#if defined(MYLIB_WIN32_AVAILABLE)
# define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
# include <windows.h>
#endif
```

When I open a VS2012 ARM Developer Prompt and compile the source file, it results in:

```
cl.exe /nologo /D_MBCS /Zi /TP /EHsc /MT /DWINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_FAMILY_APP /c wait.cpp
wait.cpp
wait.cpp(140) : error C3861: 'Sleep': identifier not found
wait.cpp(145) : error C3861: 'PulseEvent': identifier not found
wait.cpp(149) : error C2039: 'WaitForMultipleObjects' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
...
```

According to the [`Sleep` docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN, I need to include `<synchapi.h>` for Windows 8, Windows Server 2012, and Windows Phone 8.1. So I changed the include block to the following based on [Operating System Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from MSDN:

```c
// Windows 8, Windows Server 2012, and Windows Phone 8.1 need <synchapi.h>
#if (WINVER >= _WIN32_WINNT_WIN8) || (_WIN32_WINNT >= _WIN32_WINNT_WIN8)
#include <synchapi.h>
#endif
```

Then it compiles under ARM but results in a broken compile under Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 7:

```
1> wait.cpp
1> c:\users\...\wait.h(26): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'synchapi.h': No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> // Windows 8, Windows Server 2012, and Windows Phone 8.1 need <synchapi.h>
> #if (WINVER >= _WIN32_WINNT_WIN8) || (_WIN32_WINNT >= _WIN32_WINNT_WIN8)
> #include <synchapi.h>
> #endif
> ```

I needed to force include `<sdkddkver.h>` so that `WINVER` and `_WIN32_WINNT` were assigned a values. I also stopped using `_WIN32_WINNT_WIN8`:

```
#if (WINVER >= 0x0602) || (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0602)
#include <synchapi.h>
#endif
```